# Matplotlib/Pyplot: How to zoom subplots together?

Tags: zooming, matplotlib

I have plots of 3-axis accelerometer time-series data (t,x,y,z) in separate subplots I'd like to zoom together.  That is, when I use the "Zoom to Rectangle" tool on one plot, when I release the mouse all 3 plots zoom together.

Previously, I simply plotted all 3 axes on a single plot using different colors.  But this is useful only with small amounts of data: I have over 2 million data points, so the last axis plotted obscures the other two.  Hence the need for separate subplots.

I know I can capture matplotlib/pyplot mouse events (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html), and I know I can catch other events (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.ResizeEvent), but I don't know how to tell what zoom has been requested on any one subplot, and how to replicate it on the other two subplots.

I suspect I have the all the pieces, and need only that one last precious clue...

-BobC

Comment: IMO the best documentation is the example code they provide: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html

Comment: True!  I wish that page existed when I asked my question.  So good it's there now.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using the `sharex` and/or `sharey` keywords when creating the axes:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(...)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2, sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot(...)
```

Answer (score 75):

You can also do this with `plt.subplots`, if that's your style.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

I call the following function after making plots to get them linked together.  It will get all subplots from the current figure, and link their x axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def linkx():
  # Get current figure
  axes = plt.gcf().axes 
  parent = axes[0]
  # Loop over other axes and link to first axes
  for i in range(1,len(axes)): 
    axes[i].sharex(parent)
```

Answer (score -2):

Interactively this works on separate axes

```
for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
fig.draw()
```