# Brushing and linking in matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to implement the brushing and linking functionality in a matplotlib/seaborn plot? I'm aware of this functionality through [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/linked_brush.html) and [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/index.html), however I don't want to show this in a browser, I want to do it in my python script, not through a browser. I'm also aware of [glue](http://www.glueviz.org/en/stable/index.html) but it sounded to me that the functionalities are encapsulated inside the interface...

Isn't there an intuitive way of doing it within the normal libraries of seaborn, matplotlib?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *brushing and linking*. Chances are that this functionality exists under a different name.

Comment: By brushing and linking I mean a selection of a specific part of the dataset, and changes are reflected dynamically in other views. Please check the link I included under mpld3.

Comment: Do you want the views to change together if you zoom or pan one of them? [This is relatively easy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4200586/3005167). Or do you want manipulations of the data be reflected in other plots? This may be more tricky...